# Laravel : How to make a page submit to itself

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I'm working on a page for editing user profiles but I want the page am working on to submit to itself when it is submitted and show a message that the profile has been edited successfully. Please how do I do this ?

Here is what am working ?

```
        <div class="row">

          <div class="text-center title">Pricing</div>

          <div class="text-center desc col-md-8 col-md-push-2">

            {{$sitename}} 

          </div>


<div class="container" style="padding-top: 60px;">
  <h1 class="page-header">Edit Profile</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- left column -->

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/profile">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img id="ShowImage" src="#"/>
        <img src="http://localhost:8234/img/index.png" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar" width="200" height="200">
        <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>
        <input type="file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm" name="avatar_path" id="avatar_path" onchange="readURL(this);">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- edit form column -->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 personal-info">
      <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
        <a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a> 
        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        This is the <strong>Profile Page</strong>. Use this to <strong>ONLY</strong> change your peronsal details
      </div>
      <h3>Personal info</h3>
        <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['id']}}" type="hidden" name="user_id">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First Name:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['first_name']}}" type="text" name="first_name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last Name:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['last_name']}}" type="text" name="last_name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['username']}}" type="text" name="username">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email Address:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['email']}}" type="text" name="email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Gender</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="ui-select">
              <select id="gender" class="form-control" name="gender">
                <option value="{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['gender']}}" selected>{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['gender']}}</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">City:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['city']}}" type="text" name="city">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">State:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['state']}}" type="text" name="state">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Country:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['country']}}" type="text" name="country">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Mobile:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['mobile']}}" type="text" name="mobile">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Occupation:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="{{$userInfo['data']['profile']['occupation']}}" type="text" name="occupation">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="bkgrnd-blue text-white btn btn-primary" value="Update Profile" type="submit">
            <span></span>
            <a href="/profile/{{$userInfo['data']['id']}}" class="bkgrnd-blue text-white btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is your view. You have no PHP written here at all. We cant just write your code for you here. You should write the submitting in your controller and check when the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This solution came from https://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-form-submission-to-the-same-page. Hope it helps

I have done a get route to display the page. I then did route a post to post form data.

Then I passed the $data variable to blade where I did an isset to check if it is created which displays the results

Display initial page

```
public function destinationSearchGet(){
    $headData = array('pageTitle' => 'Admin Home - View all destinations');
    return view('admin.destination_search', $headData);
}
```

post data back to the same page and create a new variable

```
public function destinationSearchPost(){
    $headData = array('pageTitle' => 'Admin Home - Search results');
    $formData = Request::input('destination');
    $data = ParentRegionList::destinationSearch($formData);
    return view('admin.destination_search', $headData)->with(compact('data'))
}
```

use blade to check if it exists

```
 @if (isset($data))
   <p>{{dd($data)}}</p>
 @endif
```